# Filter by first two digit of a number in R

Tags: r, filter

My data looks like this.

```
AK  ALASKA DEPT OF PUBLIC SAFETY    1005-00-073-9421    RIFLE,5.56 MILLIMETER     
AK  ALASKA DEPT OF PUBLIC SAFETY    1005-00-073-9421    RIFLE,5.56 MILLIMETER
```

I am looking to filter the data in multiple different ways.  For example, I filter by the type of equipment, such as column 4, with the code

```
rifle.off <- city.data[[i]][city.data[[i]][,4]=="RIFLE,5.56 MILLIMETER",]
```

Where city.data is a list of matrices with data from 31 cities (so I iterate through a for loop to isolate the rifle data for each city).  I would like to also filter by the number in the third column.  Specifically, I only need to filter by the first two digits, i.e. I would like to isolate all line items where the number in column 3 begins with '10'.  How would I modify my above code to isolate only the first two digits but let all the other digits be anything?

Edit:  Providing an example of the city.data matrix as requested.  First off city.data is a list made with:

```
city.data <- list(albuq, austin, baltimore, charlotte, columbus, dallas, dc, denver, detroit)
```

where each city name is a matrix.  Each individual matrix is isolated by police department using:

```
phoenix <- vector()
for (i in 1:nrow(gun.mat)){
  if (gun.mat[i,2]=="PHOENIX DEPT OF PUBLIC SAFETY"){
    phoenix <- rbind(gun.mat[i,],phoenix)
  }
}
```

where gun.mat is just the original matrix containing all observations.  phoenix looks like

```
state         police.dept                 nsn               type      quantity  price    date.shipped    name  
AZ  PHOENIX DEPT OF PUBLIC SAFETY   1240-01-411-1265    SIGHT,REFLEX    1       331 1   3/29/13 OPTICAL SIGHTING AND RANGING EQUIPMENT
AZ  PHOENIX DEPT OF PUBLIC SAFETY   1240-01-411-1265    SIGHT,REFLEX    1       331 1   3/29/13 OPTICAL SIGHTING AND RANGING EQUIPMENT
AZ  PHOENIX DEPT OF PUBLIC SAFETY   1240-01-411-1265    SIGHT,REFLEX    1       331 1   3/29/13 OPTICAL SIGHTING AND RANGING EQUIPMENT
```

Comment: Can we please see an example of `city.data` matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
The original data that you have in the first block in the question. Subset it.

```
Rifle556<-subset(data, data$column4 == "RIFLE,5.56 MILLIMETER")
```

After that, subset the data again that **don't** start with "10" from column 3

```
s <- '10'
Rifle55610<-subset(Rifle556, grep(s, column3, invert=T)
```

This way you have the data subset according to your condition.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Why did you set the invert condition = T though?  Wouldn't that create a subset all observations except the ones that start with "10" from column 3?

Comment: Isnt that what you want?

Comment: Oh no I wanted all the observations that do start with '10' from column 3, so I'll just leave it to false.  Sorry for the confusion and thanks again.

Comment: Did you achieve what you wanted to though? I know the method is a bit different.

Comment: Sort of, the code successfully identified and created a subset of all the nsn codes starting with 10.  But I read the documentation for grep and it appears it would search for '10' anywhere within the number, so would not necessarily isolate only those beginning with 10.

Comment: My sort of messy solution was to create a separate column that contains only the first two digits of each column and then just use that column to make my selection.

Comment: It aint messy if it works. Mine is messy too then. I hope someone with grep knowledge will help.